# RuntimeWarning: NumPy invalid value encountered in power

Tags: python, numpy

There is no problem when I do the following mathematical operation in python:

```
>>> -27**(-1/3)\
-0.33333333333333337
```

When I do the same with NumPy, it gives the following error.

```
>>> a = np.array([-27])
>>> b = np.array([-1/3])\
>>> a**b
```

I get:

```
> C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:3: 
> RuntimeWarning:
> invalid value encountered in power. This is separate from the
> ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until\
> array([nan])
```

I don't quite understand what the reasoning behind this result is. Can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

You are computing `-(27)**(-1/3)` not `(-27)**(-1/3)`.

In the former, `a>0` which is valid; in the latter though, `a<0` which is an invalid operation *****.

The following Python code:

```
>>> -27**(-1/3)
-0.33333333333333337
```

Is *'equivalent'* to this NumPy code:

```
>>> a = np.array([27])
>>> b = np.array([-1/3])
>>> -a**b
array([-0.33333333])
```

---

***** Indeed, given `a>0`, and `b`, we have: `a**b = exp(log(a**b)) = exp(b*log(a))`. But `x -> log(x)` is only defined for positive real numbers.

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much.

Comment: If it helped solve your problem, consider marking the answer as correct by clicking on the green checkmark on the left.